SvelteKit route gives 500 error on reload
I've been working on a SvelteKit project for some time now. Always there has been this issue where if I reload a route other than the home page I get a 500 error. I'm new to web development.
So, I look up every search term I can think of along the lines of "SvelteKit breaks on reload." Eventually, I run into this [GitHub thread][1], which is the closest I've seen to people expressing a similar problem.
What I found is that reloading is not necessarily the culprit. If I navigate to a specific page manually by entering a url I get the same error. I've also failed to find threads discussing this.
It makes sense that this happens on paper. The pages don't exist until someone navigates to them with the router. The router mounts the page and the onMount function in all of the associated components builds the page on the spot on the client side. I understand that much. Currently this app is purely client-side and relies on client-side objects like localStorage, so server functions like load have not helped me because they cannot access localStorage.
The final straw for me was when I realized that if I navigated in and out of the same route, there would be some data that persists there in the background via history objects, which slowly corrupt the behavior of the page.
My question is: how on Earth do I make SvelteKit reload these pages without throwing a fit?

What is the error message?

I posted an answer myself since I've been working towards a solution. It's not accepted yet because I can't accept my own answer for 2 days, but it's mostly correct. I tried to fish out the error message, but the exact error was very inconsistent. Early on in development, the message of death was always window is not defined, but I was able to narrow down the problematic components and avoid the error or throw an error with a better message.

Here's a summary of the findings for clarity:
Problem: Reloading the page breaks SvelteKit.

Page relies on server data.

Use a +page.server.js file next to +page.svelte that implements the load function. Tutorial for loading page data on learn.svelte.dev


Page relies on client data.

Add if (browser) before code that uses data from the browser. This can involve window, localStorage, and others. I'm not sure where to find a comprehensive list of these properties, but localStorage is a property of the window, so it makes sense that both would go missing at the same time.



When typing my question here, StackOverflow has shown me similar errors:

How do I fix my sveltekit website throwing 500 errors when reloading it? This example came with the ambiguous answer "I put it on Netlify and it works now." My project is not currently hosted on a cloud service, but it is intended for this sort of target eventually.
Fix 500 Internal error on reload on sveltekit This provides a proposed fix to localStorage not being defined. I was able to at least make a load function that fails gracefully, but it will never succeed because it's in a server-side file trying to load data from localStorage.

I didn't see these threads before because they didn't show up on my searches, only when I went to type this question and entered the title to get StackOverflow's recommendations. Thanks StackOverflow!
After implementing a lot of if (browser) calls, I actually got one of my routes to reload properly. Doing this for every route should be very time consuming. But I guess that's my current directive. It has a very clunky reloading sequence that actually looks very promising for forgetting any data that SvelteKit has decided to keep around, though I haven't tested this against the corruption problem yet.
The issue remains that I have no idea what's going on. This isn't a problem with my project, and it looks like the if (browser) statements were the right way to go. I'm still going to post this thread because I think it's a lot more clear than the existing threads.
The question remains of how SvelteKit understands to reload the page automatically when it runs into enough of these if statements. Cool, but weird.
